# Problem with autocomplete in the Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have a problem with autocomplete in the Visual Studio Code.

Let's imagine that my code looks like that:

```
let require1 = require;
let fs = require("fs");
let fs1 = require1("fs");
```

Autocomplete works correctly for the "fs", but not for the "fs1".

Example for the "fs"

[image: 1]

Example for the "fs1"

[image: 2]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or why it doesn't work?

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this steps may be it will work
just go file->prefrences->Settings->extension->Emmet->Edit in settings.json
then paste this code `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true, "files.associations": {"*html":"html"},` 
check this may be work!!